# How to set default value in kendo ui numeric textbox?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
$('<input  maxlength="15"  name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoNumericTextBox({
        min: 0,
        max: 9999999999,
        format: "c",
        decimals: 0,
        value: 999999
    });
```

I tried like as mentioned above. But, It was not working as expected.

Comment: Any error? Something?

Comment: No, It was not throwing any error.

Comment: Then, add the error you are getting.

Comment: Sorry, I told like it was working fine except setting the default value to a numeric text box...min,max,format properties etc are working fine as expected..

Comment: Hi, for some reason the "value" property on kendo ui numeric text box is not working, but I found an alternate way to set default value for numeric text box...

schema: {
     model: {
 `CreditLimit: { type: "number", defaultValue: 999999`}
}